# Tweak output from XmlSerializer in C#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am wondering if there is a way to get XmlSerializer in C# to change what it outputs for one property of one object.  For example, if I have something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string prop1{get;}
    public uint prop2{get;}
    public MyClass2 class2{get;}
    public MyClass3 class3{get;}
}

public class MyClass2
{
    public string prop3{get;}
}

public class MyClass3
{
    //Lots of properties that I want to serialize as normal
}
```

Now in somewhere in my code, I have something like this:

```
private void SerializeStuff(List<MyClass> list, string path)
{
    XmlSerializer serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);
    serialize.Serialize(writer, list);
    writer.Close();
}
```

What I want is for the serialization to work as normal, but with `prop3` replaced with some other stuff.  Example:

```
<MyClass>
    <prop1>whatever</prop1>
    <prop2>345</prop2>
    <class2>
        <somethingNotProp3>whatever</somethingNotProp3>
        <somethingElseNotProp3>whatever</somethingElseNotProp3>
    </class2>
    <class3>
        ...
    </class3>
</MyClass>
```

Is there a way to customize XmlSerializer so I don't have to write the entire Xml file manually, or is there no way to do that?

Edit:
I am pretty sure that the solution could have something to do with implementing `ISerializable`'s `GetObjectData` method; however, I am not exactly sure how to implement it.  I tried making `MyClass2` inherit from `ISerializable` and implementing `GetObjectData`, but nothing changed. `prop3` was still output in the XML file.

Comment: Yes you can, but what do you want to change? Just the name of the prop in the xml?

Comment: @Matt: The name of the property and also the value. (I mean that the string `"whatever"` is not the value of any property in `class2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the attributes in the [`System.Xml.Serialization` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.aspx) to affect the way that the instance is serialized.

If you need very specialized serialization for `MyClass3` that the attributes cannot handle, then implement the [`IXmlSerializable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) which will give you complete control over the serialization process (you can even decide on an instance-by-instance basis how to serialize the content/property).

Based on the comments, it would seem that you want to implement `IXmlSerializable`, as you want to change the name of the property *and* the value; the attributes will let you change the name of the property/element/attribute, but not allow you to perform transformations on the value (and I assume you don't want to corrupt your representation and add an extra property/value for this purpose).

Comment: I believe that you are right about that; however, I cannot find the documentation on MSDN about how to change the element name _and_ value.

Comment: Ah I get it now.  I didn't understand how the WriteXml `method` worked.  This has been very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way so that if I do something like `writer.WriteStartElement("element"); writer.WriteEndElement();`, it will output `<element></element>` instead of `<element />`? Edit: Never mind, MSDN says there's no way to do that.