# null elements not showing in response xml (SOAP web service)

Tags: .net, xml, web-services

I've created an asp.net web service for a client of ours which returns multiple `List` objects containing complex types. The client has been receiving data just fine.

He has noticed though that not all the tags are there all the time. If, for example, I return 3 objects in my list, objects A B and C. and C is null when I return it. It will show:

```
<A>data</A>
<B>data</B>
```

When I would like it to show the following:

```
<A>data</A>
<B>data</B>
<C/>
```

Or at least:

```
<A>data</A>
<B>data</B>
<C></C>
```

Basically, I want the structure of the XML to remain the same regardless of what data is available and what data is null.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639312/can-you-add-additional-properties-to-net-serialized-null-values speaks about namespaces but you have to use the same attribute.

Comment: Do you have minOccurs="0" attribute on C element in schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Soap spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/) states:

> A NULL value or a default value MAY be represented by omission of the accessor element. A NULL value MAY also be indicated by an accessor element containing the attribute xsi:null with value '1' or possibly other application-dependent attributes and values.

Unfortunately for You MS has chosen first option for this situation.

On the other hand you could not make NULL value like this:

```
<C></C>
```

because how would You differ between empty string and null?

This option

```
<C/>
```

looks promising. I'm guessing your service uses XMLSerializer to serialize your data. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286112/tweak-output-from-xmlserializer-in-c-sharp). Maybe you can implement `IXMLSerializable` for your object and provide custom xml for your data.